# Exception using zmq upon completion

Tags: multithreading, c++11, zeromq

I am trying to set up an internal multithreaded relay using ZMQ, but I am getting an exception after a ZMQ_PAIR processing is completed from somewhere within ZMQ, and I am just not seeing why.   I dumbed it down to the bare minimum and it is nearly identical with what is on the ZMQ relay sample http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:mtrelay and the problem still occurs.  For the life of me, I cannot see where I went wrong.  The only thing I see different is that I am using std::thread instead of posix threads.

Here is the code:

```
void Message::GetMessage(const MessageDefn &defn) {

    zmq::context_t context(1);
    zmq::message_t message;

    zmq::socket_t receiver(context, ZMQ_PAIR);
    receiver.bind("inproc://parser");

    std::thread parser(&Message::ParseData, this, &context);

    receiver.recv(&message);

    // Error occurs here, after returning
    return;
}

void *Message::GetData( zmq::context_t *ctx) {
    zmq::socket_t sender(*ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    sender.connect("inproc://requestor");
    sender.send("Response", 8);
    return NULL;
};

void *Message::ParseData(zmq::context_t *ctx) {
    zmq::socket_t receiver(*ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    receiver.bind("inproc://requestor");

    std::thread requestor(&Message::GetData, this, ctx);

    zmq::message_t response(100);
    receiver.recv(&response);

    zmq::socket_t sender(*ctx, ZMQ_PAIR);
    sender.connect("inproc://parser");

    sender.send("Parsed", 6);

    return NULL;
}
```

Here is what comes back from VS2013 debugger

```
The thread 'std::_LaunchPad<std::_Bind<1,void * __ptr64,std::_Pmf_wrap<void * __ptr64 (__cdecl Server::Message::*)(zmq::context_t * __ptr64) __ptr64,void * __ptr64,Server::Message,zmq::context_t * __ptr64>,Server::Message * __ptr64,zmq::context_t * __ptr64> >::_Go' (0x2460) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Debug Error!

Program: D:\Projects\build\Debug\AppTest.exe

R6010
- abort() has been called


(Press Retry to debug the application)
```

EDIT #2:

Ok, so I am wondering if there is a problem with some combination of nuget package of ZMQ, Visual Studio 2013, and/or x64.  I am using the nuget package http://www.nuget.org/packages/libzmq_vc120.    I created a brand new 64bit console project that had nothing more than the hello world client.   http://zguide.zeromq.org/cpp:hwclient, and then I had to add the c++ wrapper https://github.com/zeromq/cppzmq/blob/master/zmq.hpp

When I run it, all I get is Sending Hello 0a  (the a is actually an accented a ie. `a), and then it hangs.   No receive is ever handled.

Am I using the wrong nuget package?   Does anyone have this running under VS2013 that can share how they set it up?

Comment: can you tell us (edit your question) what the exception actually is?

Comment: Doh!   Forgot to put the error message in!   Thanks.

Comment: thanks! Can you deduct where it happens by stepping through your code/inserting breakpoints before your ZMQ calls?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  It actually occurs on the return of the main function GetMessage.  I can't even to a step-into when at the return.   It just dies.  I tried closing the sockets before the return, but that doesn't change anything.   *baffled*

Comment: I'm baffled, too. :(

Comment: I started fresh new basic project....strange behavior.   Is my setup and install correct?